# AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-16657

Tags: swift, objective-c, fairplay, avassetdownloadtask

I'm using [AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaggregateassetdownloadtask) to download **HLS** videos in my application. I just added a **pause/resume** functionality. Simply, I'm suspending the task when the user wants to pause the download.

**But**, somehow in this case, actually task won't stop. It keeps downloading the asset. When I press the resume button I'm calling the task's .resume() method. Somehow, the process going super fast till the **%100,** and it gives an error (keep reading or goto **Error Message** title).

### How do I test

- Start to download an item via AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask
- Tap Pause at the %3.
- Call the task?.suspend()
- Wait for 1 minute or 2
- Tap the resume download button
- Call the task?.resume()
- Task resumes from %29
- Task fails at %48

## Code

```
@objc public func pauseDownload(for productId: String) {
    var asset: Asset?
    var task: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask?
    for (taskKey, assetValue) in activeDownloadsMap where productId == assetValue.productId {
        asset = assetValue
        task = taskKey
        task?.suspend() // **task is not nil!**
        break
    }

    // Here: I'm sending a notification to the UI cases
}

@objc public func resumeDownload(for productId: String) {
    var asset: Asset?
    var task: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask?
    for (taskKey, assetValue) in activeDownloadsMap where productId == assetValue.productId {
        asset = assetValue
        task = taskKey
        task?.resume() // **task is not nil!**
        break
    }

    // Here: I'm sending a notification to the UI cases
}
```

### Other Cases

- Without suspending the task, it downloads flawlessly.

### Technical Details

- Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)
- iOS Version 14.4

### Error Message

#### Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-16657

"(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"BackgroundAVAssetDownloadTask .<1>"), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundAVAssetDownloadTask .<1>}

#### developer.apple.com

Here is the same issue at developer.apple.com:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674090

## Reported Bug

### FB9043262

If you believe you are faced with the same issue, please consider the help.

Best.

Comment: I was running into this issue too. It looks like it has been fixed in the current version of iOS 14.

Comment: Same here, iPhone X iOS 14.2, Xcode 12.4 (12D4e) 

Comment: Find `AVAssetDownloadURLSession` soooo buggy... Apple's API are nice but `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`, well, what happened? 

Comment: iOS14? Please fist update your iOS, probably that’ll fix.

Comment: That is not something I am gonna tell to my users who want to stay on iOS 14. For whatever reason.

Comment: I can understand that of course :) But this was fixed after iOS14.2, you can go till iOS14.8, it will work, I hope :) And still, you'll be in the iOS14.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this error on iOS 16.1

```
Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-16657 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundAVAssetDownloadTask <6B7F1201-FF3E-4B81-B3C5-6C85D8718BDA>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundAVAssetDownloadTask <6B7F1201-FF3E-4B81-B3C5-6C85D8718BDA>.<2>}
```

It seems that a change in `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` as part of iOS16 is causing the the root `.m3u8` to be retrieved multiple times.

We generate these root `.m3u8` playlists on-the-fly and put a token on URIs pointing to child subtitle `.m3u8` files.  Each time the root playlist was retrieved a new token was generated, and it had a slightly different URI for the subtitle playlist.  In a proxyman network trace, we could see both subtitle playlists being retrieved, and the eventual `.vtt` subtitle files coming from the URIs specified in the second playlist.

Ensuring a consistent URI value for the subtitle playlist across multiple root playlist retrievals fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'm seeing the same issue. Can you please provide more detail on the consistent URI part? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide more information how can we solve this issue @user2735792.

Comment: I faced the same issue with media playlists and not with master playlist. Having different URI generated for the same media playlist URL, and downloading multiple streams at the same time generate the logs `downloading media failed validation check` and `download failed with error -16657`